# TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

following is a code to get the emails into the stdin, and do some filtering to extract the ticket-id from email then send it to telegram.
but when i run the code it returns the following error type.

> TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

I have made the tikid to `str(tikid)`, the i receive no issues but no messages are getting send to telegram function.

the code is:

```
import re
import sys
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = 'mytoken_id_here'
    bot_chatID = 'my_chatid_here'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)
    return response.json()

for myline in sys.stdin:
      tikid = re.findall("ticket/\d+", myline)
      if (len(tikid)) > 0:
          tikid = output.replace("ticket/", "")
          print(tikid)

telegram_bot_sendtext(tikid)
```

**Email-Content**

```
--===============7235995302665768439==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<div dir="rtl"><html>
<head>
   Ticket generated ....     
</head>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><a href="http://example.com/show/ticket/1735" target="_blank">http://example.com/show/ticket/1735</a></p>
</body>
</html>
</div>
--===============7235995302665768439==--
```

**OUTPUT**

root@server:~# cat email.txt  | /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/scrip/telegram-piper

````
1735
1735
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/scripts/telegram-piper.py", line 22, in <module>
    telegram_bot_sendtext(tikid)
  File "/usr/local/scripts/telegram-piper.py", line 9, in telegram_bot_sendtext
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly```
````

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: When asking questions about errors, always include the full and complete copy-paste of the output. And add a comment on the line where the error happens. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Can you also include the expected input, and the desired output (if applicable)

Comment: Please add that information in the question itself by editing it. There's a link named `edit` right below the line of tags.

Comment: `bot_message` is a list and not a string. What does it contain?

Comment: yes correct, but when i changed  `telegram_bot_sendtext(str(tikid))`. No error but the function not works. meaning nothing is getting sent to telegram api.

Comment: Can you add that information to the original question, and format it? You can do so by clicking `edit` underneath the post :)

Comment: @RightmireM- done. added to the original question

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, information added.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.
By using ' '.join

```
import re
import sys
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = 'mytoken_id_here'
    bot_chatID = 'my_chatid_here'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)
    return response.json()

for myline in sys.stdin:
      tikid = re.findall("ticket/\d+", myline)
      if (len(tikid)) > 0:
         output = str(tikid[0])
         tikid = output.replace("ticket/", "")
         new_value=''.join(tikid)


telegram_bot_sendtext(new_value)
```